# Sed to match any aws arn regex

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to find aws arn from logs and change its color

regex I tried

```
echo 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:421142534505:function:list-users"' |  sed -e "s/arn:\S*[^\s\"]/$(tput bold setaf 1)&$(tput setaf 9)/gi"
```

result I got

[image]

I want `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:421142534505:function:list-users` to be colored (any whitespace or " should not be colored)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "s/arn:aws[^\" ]*/$(tput setaf 1)&$(tput sgr 0)/g" input_file
```